# Visual Studio 2015 another installation in progress

Tags: visual-studio, process, installation, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 COmmunity Edition I am at ~98% of the installation, now the program tells me:

> another installation is in progress, try it later...

I do not know how to solve this issue.

And I actually do not want to restart the computer because the installation already took me over 2 days.

I am open for all ideas.

Answer (score 13):

My problem was that I had launched the installer twice, by mistake.

So a quick fix was opening **`Task Manager > Processes`** and killing the two instances of **`msiexec.exe`** that were visible.

The next run was successful without issue.

For another list of solutions that helped others:

- [Visual Studio MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8734e43-d325-4b67-9843-ddbd4430e73a/another-installation-is-in-progress-please-wait-to-retry-again?forum=vssetup)
- [SQL Server MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7a3a40f2-d70a-4bd9-b477-735fd443b1e5/another-installation-is-in-progress-please-wait-to-try-again?forum=vssetup)
- [How To Solutions](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2015/08/solving-installation-is-stuck-problem-in-visual-studio-community-edition/#.VeirNVJm4hl)

Comment: Even rebooting did not spot msiexec! This worked liek a charm

Answer (score -1):

I googled this problem, and found some complicated advice about failed installations and the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility. But I find that this error occurs when a program installs just fine in every respect except that it leaves the Windows Installer Service running.

There’s a easy way to fix this.

Right-click on the Computer icon, wherever it exists on your system, and select Manage. (I’m using the Classic Start menu, so the Computer icon is on my desktop. If you’re using the new Start menu, the icon is in the Start menu.) This opens the Computer Management utility.

Below is link for more details:

http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2008/12/another-installation-already-in-progress-but-its-not/

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/343255/Another-program-is-being-installed-Please-wait-unt

Comment: I have to reboot the computer in those "solutions"

Comment: Yes try once lets see what happens, I think this only the solution. @JohnDoesLegacy